# Getting ArgumentError wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, arguments

When I run my application I am getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError in StatesController#filter

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
    def filter(my_string)

        @new_array = []
        @new_array = state.each {|x| if /#my_string/i =~ x then puts x end}
        return @new_array

    end

end
```

And my view looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>States</title>
  </head>

  <body>

        <% States.filter(params[:substring]) %>
        <p><%= @new_array.each %></p>
        <% if @new_array.size = 0 %>
        <p>No matches!</p>

    </body>

</html>
```

What wrong with my code?

thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter method you have in the StatesController is an action. Such actions do not accept parameters. A better way to achieve what you are trying to do would be to create a model called State like so. And add the filter method to it:

```
# app/models/state.rb
class State
  def filter(params[:my_string])
    @new_array = []
    @new_array = state.each {|x| if /#my_string/i =~ x then puts x end}
    return @new_array
  end
end
```

In your controller, you should now have something like the following:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  def filter
    @states = State.filter(params[:sub_string])
  end
end
```

Then in the corresponding view:

```
<% if @states.empty? %>
  <p>No matches!</p>
<% else %>
  <p>
    <% @states.each do |state| %>
      <%= state %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

What this does is uses the model to load an array into an instance variable. This instance variable (started with the @) is accessible in the view that is rendered in the controller action. The action we are using is specified as filter.

In the view, I check if there are any results in the array by using the empty? method. Otherwise i just loop through the array.

Now, this will only work provided you have the params[:sub_string] in the headers. So you will need to make sure you have something like `?sub_string=mystring` in the url.

Given your question, and your code layout, I would assume you are fairly new to rails. I really recommend having a good read through the getting started guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your very clear, easy to understand answer...and thanks for the link!!

Comment: Not a problem. There's a few good books around that you can look into as well for learning Rails. I haven't read it myself, but friends of mine really recommend "The Rails 3 way" for new comers.

Comment: Another question now - when I tried to test it, I got the following error:You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.empty?

How come I can't access the array?

Comment: That's probably the state variable in the controller action. You will need to set it to value.